# Visual Studio line highlight in Debug mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-studio-2012

When I'm debugging my code, in most cases the the debugged line is highlighted (by Visual Studio debugger) with the Yellow background. Here is the screenshot:
[image]

But, in some case the debugged line is highlighted with Orange background: Here is the screenshot:
[image]

Also, sometimes when I'm pressed F10 button the code line background changed from Yellow to Orange and vise versa. What is the pattern behind those changes?

PS -
I wonder if this is somehow related to the fact that my program has two separate threads that are running in the background?

Comment: Is it maybe orange because it's a combination of yellow (current executing line) and red (breakpoint)?

Comment: The orange is when you have multiple threads running.

Comment: I don't think this is related to winforms. It would be great if you could replace the winforms-tag with the version of VS, because the coloring very likely depends on the version

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I wonder if this is somehow related to the fact that my program has two separate threads

Yes, very much so.  The orange background color is meant to warn you that a thread context switch occurred and you are no longer debugging the thread you previously looked at.  Note the blue exclamation overlay on the arrow, an extra warning.

Some sample code that makes it crystal clear:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        new Thread(Example).Start();
        new Thread(Example).Start();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void Example() {
        var rng = new Random(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        for (int loop = 0; loop < 10000; ++loop) {
            Thread.Sleep(rng.Next(0, 100));
            Thread.Sleep(rng.Next(0, 100));
            Thread.Sleep(rng.Next(0, 100));
            Thread.Sleep(rng.Next(0, 100));
            Thread.Sleep(rng.Next(0, 100));
            Thread.Sleep(rng.Next(0, 100));
            Thread.Sleep(rng.Next(0, 100));
        }
    }
}
```

Set a breakpoint on one of the Thread.Sleep() calls.  Press F5 and execution will stop at the breakpoint.  The background is yellow.  Use Debug > Windows > Threads, note the yellow arrow on the current thread.

Now press F10.

One of three things can happen, the outcome is completely random:

- You step to the next statement in the same thread.
- The second thread might hit the breakpoint as well.
- The second thread might be the first to land on a statement and trigger a debugger break.

Also observe the yellow marker in the Threads debugger window.  In the first bullet that marker did not move, the same thread activated the break.  The background color is *yellow*.  If the marker did move, thus matching the last 2 bullets then the background color is *orange*.

Press F10 repeatedly to get all the possible outcomes.  And note that the background color choice is an exact match with whether or not the current thread changed in the Threads window.  The third bullet is the likeliest outcome in this sample program.

Next experiment you should try is right-clicking the other thread in the Threads window and selecting Freeze.  Pressing F10 now consistently hits the same thread and the highlight is always yellow.  The kind of thing you need to do when debugging threads becomes too difficult.

Long story short, knowing that you are debugging a different thread is rather important.  Local variables and stack trace might be quite different.  The orange background and the blue exclamation warns you about it.